# I overstayed in the USA about 20 years ago and I worked. Can apply for a new visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, legal, b1-b2-visas, overstaying

I got my B2 visa 20 years ago and I overstayed for about four years and I worked illegally.

I have a plan to go on a business trip to Las Vegas. I'm not sure what to say to the official if I'm asked if I worked back then. I paid taxes to the IRS and had an SSN, It was not legal to work but I used that number then.

Never got a ticket or trouble there.

Comment: How long has it been since you left the U.S.?

Comment: @mts looks like roughly 16 years

Comment: I left US about 20 years ago